# Drawing concentric ellipses with text with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw three concentric ellipses with tikz which all contain some text, with the final picture looking similar to this:

[image]

How is this possible?

Comment: I think the rationale of [Ellipses aligned on the same boundary point](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/476882/13304) could help.

Comment: Those are not concentric, are they?

Answer (score 4):

[image: formatted text and math]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\angle{60}%
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\xoff}{2cm*cos(\angle)}%
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\yoff}{1cm*sin(\angle)}%
\draw [thick, fill=gray!10] (\xoff,\yoff) circle[x radius=8cm, y radius=4cm] ++(3*\xoff,3*\yoff) node{Text3};
\draw [thick, fill=gray!50] (0.5*\xoff,0.5*\yoff) circle[x radius=5cm, y radius=2.5cm] ++(1.5*\xoff,1.5*\yoff) node{Text2};
\draw [thick, fill=gray!80] (0,0) circle[x radius=2cm, y radius=1cm] node{Text 1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment by @ClaudioFiandrino, I was able to produce this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [thick, fill=gray!10] (0,-1) arc (-90:270:5cm and 3cm);
\draw [thick, fill=gray!50] (0,-0.5) arc (-90:270:3.5cm and 2cm);
\draw [thick, fill=gray!80] (0,0) arc (-90:270:2cm and 1cm);
\node [yshift=1cm] (0,0) {Text 1};
\node [yshift=2.5cm] (0,0) {Text 2};
\node [yshift=4cm] (0,0) {Text 3};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which looks fine enough for my purposes.

Nonetheless, I would still be interested in figuring out how to have the ellipses and text "diagonally" aligned rather than stacked on top of each other